# Context-menu actions on Dojo Charts

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting, dojox.gfx

I'd like to implement a context menu over some of plot elements in a Dojo Chart. Unfortunately, out of the box Dojo Chart supports only three events: "click", "mouseover", and "mouseout". I am not sure whether it is a limitation of dojox.gfx module or the dojox.charing. I can handle a right click event on the container DOM node and then work my way down the chart, but that does not feel the right Dojo way.

Is there an "action" or a patch to support right-click events on the Dojo Charts?

Answer (score 2):

If you use d3 for charting, you can use Dojo widget to add context menu to your d3 chart elements. and it will work fine.